# Custom validator for nested field in serializer

Tags: python, django, validation, django-rest-framework, serialization

In my **BookSerializer**, I have a nested field **page**:

```
class PageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...

class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    page = PageSerializer()
```

and the **page** field validator expects an dictionary as value. But what I want is it should accept an integer as well (page's id). So in the **BookSerializer**, I tried to override the **validate** function for the page field but it didn't work:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    page = PageSerializer()

    def validate_page(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, int):
            return value

        # if value is not an integer, reuse the default validator
        # but django said that validate_page is not a function
        return super().validate_page()
```

Seems like the **validate_page** function is never called because it's a nested field.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Correct way to create custom validation is:

```
def validate_page(self, value):
    if isinstance(value, int):
        return value
    return value
```

But it won't be working.

You need override to_internal function on Page serializer:

```
class PageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return get_object_or_404(Page, pk=data)
    ...

class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    page = PageSerializer()
```